# How do I disable boot from usb on my laptop?

Tags: boot, bios, uefi

I have a HP Notebook PC 15-ac020nk, dual boot (Windows and Linux). I would disable boot from USB, but this option is not found in the BIOS.

Do you have ideas to disable the boot from usb?

I tried to put a password on the bios, but you can always enter via  <kbd>F9</kbd> on the keyboard.

Bios version

[image]

Boot option

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: What I have found discusses enabling the ability to boot from USB. This answer is in reverse order.*

Go into `BIOS > System Configuration > Boot Options` and `Enable` **Secure Boot**.

[image]

According to the [article](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/how-to-boot-from-usb-on-HP-ENVY-15-k000nx-Notebook-PC/td-p/4379722) I read, this should disable the option to boot from USB. Also, take notice of the note under #6 in [HP PCs - Recovering your computer from a USB flash drive](http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-ENVY-15-Notebook-PC-series/6936206/model/7158164/document/c04346420#disable_secure_boot_notebook). Again, I am suggesting the reveres of these instructions.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work despite the activation of secure boot